# Zurb Foundation framework not working properly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a neat little responsive website and I come across consistent problems, and I can't seem to be able to pinpoint the problem.

Whenever I'm making a menu and use

or other elements, they turn into plain html e.g.: all list elements will have bullets and be simply plain text, without any background.

Attached is an example image:

[image]

My code for this is:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is another example:

[image]

And my code is:

```
              <div class="row" style="float: right; display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;"> 

                <button type="button" 
                        id="voltage_button"
                        onclick="measureVoltage();">
                    Voltage
                </button>

                <button type="button" 
                        id="octiv_current_button"
                        onclick="measureCurrent();">
                    Current
                </button>

                <button type="button" 
                        id="phase_button"
                        onclick="measurePhase();">
                    Phase
                </button>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what you want exactly, and it's kinda difficult to understand what you want, but as far as I understand, you want the bullet points to disappear and also inlining the menu.

HTML:

```
 <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a href="#">Web</a></h1>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Voltage</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Current</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Phase</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

JS:

```
$(document).foundation();
```

Comment: Sorry I messed up the post, now you should be able to see the images. This should give you a better insight on the issue. The 2nd image is best example. It should be a button that when pressed, should drop down with the Voltage, Current, Phase as sub menu. But it's not working properly.

Comment: Okay, have you looked at the Foundation Docs? Here's a link that should be pretty helpfull for your situation - http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/dropdown.html

Comment: Did you figure it out? If you didn't, then take a look at the code that I've posted. It's should work the way you want it :)